# Search string at the beginnig of line is not returned by regex and lines with $ are not ignored

Tags: python, regex

From a text file I want to extract everything that starts with specific "keyword" including the keyword, until a "end_word" but not the end_word itself. New line characters must be returned as well. Every extracted string is stored in a dictionary.
I have the following code in Python which works except:

**That I do not get the starting keyword in my output and that all lines starting with $ are extracted as well...**

```
import re
keywords = [ "GRID" , "CHEXA" , "FORCE" , "FORCE*" , "MOMENT" , "MOMENT*"  ]
end_words = [ "GRID" , "CHEXA" , "FORCE" ,  "FORCE*" , "MOMENT" , "MOMENT*" , "\$" ]

# Create a regular expression pattern
end_words_pattern = "|".join(f"(?=.*{re.escape(word)})" for word in end_words)
    
# Read the file
CardsFound = {}
with open("D:/home/bdf_in_test_full.dat", "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    for keyword in keywords:
        pattern = fr"^{re.escape(keyword)}((?:.*\n)+?(?={end_words_pattern}\n))"   
        matches = re.findall(pattern, file_data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
        CardsFound[keyword] = matches

for keyword in keywords:
    print(CardsFound[keyword])
    print("\n\n")
```

My input sample looks like this:

```
      $$
$$  GRID Data
$$
GRID           1        0.0     37.4999819.99999
GRID           2        -13.750233.8154619.99999
GRID           3        130.0   -405.0  39.99871
CHEXA      32662       2   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          55490   48762   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
CHEXA      32663       2   76683   48933   13278   48931   88177   55494
+          17304   55490
CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924
+          55488   48760
$  PSHELL Data                                                                 
$  PSOLID Data                                                                 
$HWCOLOR PROP                  2       3
PSOLID         2       1       0                                
$HWCOLOR PROP                 14       4
PSOLID        14       1       0                                
$$
$$  MAT1 Data
$$
$  PBAR Data                                                                   
$  MAT1 Data                                                                   
$HMNAME MAT                    1"steel" "MAT1"
$HWCOLOR MAT                   1       3
MAT1           1200000.0        0.3     0.0                             
$$
$$
$$
$$  SPC Data
$$
SPC            1    2656     123     0.0
SPC            1    2697      23     0.0
SPC            1    3239       3     0.0
$$
$$  FORCE Data
$$
FORCE          2    2699       01.0     1000.0  0.0     0.0     
FORCE          3    2699       01.0     0.0     1000.0  0.0     
FORCE          4    2699       01.0     0.0     0.0     1000.0  
FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.
*       .57735          .57735          .57735
FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9
*       -.0330417       -.0458638       .998401
$ Nodal Forces of Load Set : W06_MZFW_Gust_VB_TMSet102
MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7
*       .188616         .979433         .071665
MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7
*       .966316         .257311         .00498565
$
```

These lines in the text file

```
CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924
+          55488   48760
$  PSHELL Data
```

should return a entry in the dict like this:

```
'CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924\n+          55488   48760'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a debugger and start with a small regex and slowly build it to determine where you are wrong

```py
import re
keywords = [ "GRID" , "CHEXA" , "FORCE" , "FORCE*" , "MOMENT" , "MOMENT*"  ]
end_words = [ "GRID" , "CHEXA" , "FORCE" ,  "FORCE*" , "MOMENT" , "MOMENT*" , "$" ]

# Create a regular expression pattern
end_words_pattern = "|".join(f"(^{re.escape(word)})" for word in end_words)

# Read the file
CardsFound = {}
with open("D:/home/bdf_in_test_full.dat", "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    for keyword in keywords:
        pattern = fr"^({re.escape(keyword)} [\s\S]*?)(?={end_words_pattern})"
        matches = re.findall(pattern, file_data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
        CardsFound[keyword] = [m[0] for m in matches]

for keyword in keywords:
    print(keyword, ':')
    print(CardsFound[keyword])
    print("\n\n")
```

---

**Edit** Based on the new information about the file format.

The searched cards have line continuation characters at the next line. If line starts with `+` or `*` it is a continuation line.

```py
import re
keywords = [ "GRID", "CHEXA", "FORCE", "FORCE*", "MOMENT", "MOMENT*" ]

CardsFound = {}
with open("D:/home/bdf_in_test_full.dat", "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    for keyword in keywords:
        pattern = fr"^({re.escape(keyword)} .*?)^(?![+*])"
        matches = re.findall(pattern, file_data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
        if matches:
            CardsFound[keyword] = [m.strip() for m in matches]

for keyword in keywords:
    if not keyword in CardsFound: continue
    print(keyword, ':')
    for m in CardsFound[keyword]:
        print(m)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
GRID :
GRID           1        0.0     37.4999819.99999
GRID           2        -13.750233.8154619.99999
GRID           3        130.0   -405.0  39.99871


CHEXA :
CHEXA      32662       2   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          55490   48762   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
CHEXA      32663       2   76683   48933   13278   48931   88177   55494
+          17304   55490
CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924
+          55488   48760


FORCE :
FORCE          2    2699       01.0     1000.0  0.0     0.0
FORCE          3    2699       01.0     0.0     1000.0  0.0
FORCE          4    2699       01.0     0.0     0.0     1000.0


FORCE* :
FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.
*       .57735          .57735          .57735
FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9
*       -.0330417       -.0458638       .998401


MOMENT* :
MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7
*       .188616         .979433         .071665
MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7
*       .966316         .257311         .00498565
```

Comment: @Lumpi update my answer based on new file format specs and both solutions do not have flaw `1)`

Answer (score 2):

Use anything other than a `+` as the ending keyword.

```
(?ms)^(GRID.+?)^(?!\+)
```

Here is an example, where *string* is the input data.

```py
keywords = ['GRID', 'CHEXA', 'FORCE', 'FORCE*', 'MOMENT', 'MOMENT*']

CardsFound = {}

for k in keywords:
    CardsFound[k] = re.findall(rf'(?ms)^({re.escape(k)}.+?)^(?!\+)', string)

for k, v, in CardsFound.items():
    for s in v: print(str.strip(s))
    print()
```

Output

```
GRID           1        0.0     37.4999819.99999
GRID           2        -13.750233.8154619.99999
GRID           3        130.0   -405.0  39.99871

CHEXA      32662       2   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          55490   48762   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
CHEXA      32663       2   76683   48933   13278   48931   88177   55494
+          17304   55490
CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924
+          55488   48760

FORCE          2    2699       01.0     1000.0  0.0     0.0
FORCE          3    2699       01.0     0.0     1000.0  0.0
FORCE          4    2699       01.0     0.0     0.0     1000.0
FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.
FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9

FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.
FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9

MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7
MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7

MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7
MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7
```

---

Edit

> *"... 1) When searching eg for the keyword "FORCE" also the rows starting with "FORCE*" are read for that keyword. ..."*

Assert that the character following the keyword is not a `*`.

```
(?ms)^(FORCE(?!\*).+?)^(?!\+)
```

> *"... 2) The continuation rows staring with + are treated correct. The same should happen for continuation rows starting with *. ..."*

You can place the `+` and `*` in a *character class*.

```
(?ms)^(FORCE(?!\*).+?)^(?![+*])
```

Here is the re-factor.

```py
keywords = ['GRID', 'CHEXA', 'FORCE', 'FORCE*', 'MOMENT', 'MOMENT*']
CardsFound = {}
for k in keywords:
    CardsFound[k] = re.findall(rf'(?ms)^({re.escape(k)}(?!\*).+?)^(?![+*])', string)
for k, v, in CardsFound.items():
    for s in v: print(str.strip(s))
    print()
```

Output

```
GRID           1        0.0     37.4999819.99999
GRID           2        -13.750233.8154619.99999
GRID           3        130.0   -405.0  39.99871

CHEXA      32662       2   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          55490   48762   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
+          51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177
CHEXA      32663       2   76683   48933   13278   48931   88177   55494
+          17304   55490
CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924
+          55488   48760

FORCE          2    2699       01.0     1000.0  0.0     0.0
FORCE          3    2699       01.0     0.0     1000.0  0.0
FORCE          4    2699       01.0     0.0     0.0     1000.0

FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.
*       .57735          .57735          .57735
FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9
*       -.0330417       -.0458638       .998401


MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7
*       .188616         .979433         .071665
MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7
*       .966316         .257311         .00498565
```

Comment: You almost made it ! Only 2 flaws: 1) When searching eg for the keyword "FORCE" also the rows starting with "FORCE*" are read for that keyword. 2) The continuation rows staring with + are treated correct. The same should happen for continuation rows starting with *. The solution for2) is CardsFound[keywords[i]] = re.findall(rf'(?ms)^({re.escape(keywords[i])}.+?)^(?!\+)^(?!\*)', file_data)   but I have not found the solution for 1)

Comment: what is the use of `enumerate`

Comment: @rioV8, forgot I used _enumerate_, I don't code in Python often.  I'll adjust it, thanks!

Comment: @Lumpi, I've updated my answer.  Regarding the `*`, use a _look-ahead_ to assert the character following the _keyword_ is not a `*`.  For example, `(?ms)^(FORCE(?!\*).+?)^(?![+*])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use rioV8 solution which works fine, and just use re.finditer and re.sub,
then you will get what you want.

```py
for keyword in keywords:
    pattern = fr"^({re.escape(keyword)}[\s\S]*?)(?={end_words_pattern})"
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, txt, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

    for match in matches:
        if match.group():
            print(re.sub(r'\n[+*]', r"", match.group()))
```

```
GRID           1        0.0     37.4999819.99999

GRID           2        -13.750233.8154619.99999

GRID           3        130.0   -405.0  39.99871

CHEXA      32662       2   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177          55490   48762   51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177          51318   76683   48931   14427   76517   88177

CHEXA      32663       2   76683   48933   13278   48931   88177   55494          17304   55490

CHEXA      32664       2   51311   76677   88177   76517   14422   48924          55488   48760

FORCE          2    2699       01.0     1000.0  0.0     0.0     

FORCE          3    2699       01.0     0.0     1000.0  0.0     

FORCE          4    2699       01.0     0.0     0.0     1000.0  

FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.       .57735          .57735          .57735

FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9       -.0330417       -.0458638       .998401

FORCE*   29              7928000         102             0.       .57735          .57735          .57735

FORCE*   29              7929000         102            16221.9       -.0330417       -.0458638       .998401

MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7       .188616         .979433         .071665

MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7       .966316         .257311         .00498565

MOMENT*  30              7906000         102            1.02446+7       .188616         .979433         .071665

MOMENT*  30              7907000         102            1.4082+7       .966316         .257311         .00498565
```